# create a signal in frequency domain having values for frequency(MHZ) and power (dBm)

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, simulink, spectrum

This is my first question on this site, so I'm sorry if I do something wrong...

What I want is to convert a `signal` (which I recorded with a`Spectrum Analyzer` from `Texas Instruments`) from `frequency domain` to `time domain`.

The problem is that the software for the Analyzer can be configured just to show `frequency domain`, so I can't see `signals` in `time domain`. I recorded my signal and I exported it to an `Excel` file. In that file I have a column with `frequencies` and another column with `powers`. How can I create a signal using these 2 vectors in `Matlab` / `Simulink` and then convert it in time domain?

Answer (score 1):

The spectrum analyser has gotten you each of the wave frequencies in the original frequency. (To a certain accuracy)

Firstly you will need to convert the dBV power of the signal to V. A formula for this can be found on google. ---logarithmic formulae are tricky formula to type out---

Lets say you have a peak at 5Hz with an amplitude of 3V and one at 7Hz with a amplitude of 2V. (You can have as many waves as you like)

**1 rad = 1/(2*pi) Hz**

That means: 5Hz = 10*pi rad   and    7Hz = 14*pi rad

Now that you you have the frequency in radians you can make the wave. By a summation of cosines.

**x(t) = A.cos(wt + [phase shift])**

`w = wave frequency (rad)
A = wave amplitude (V)
t = time`

So your wave is:

**x(t) = 3.cos(10*pi*t) + 2.cos(14*pi*t)**

x(t) is now your output wave. The units are in V but can be converted back to dBV if you'd like. You can specify how long the wave should be, or how many intervals the wave has by assigning a row vector to t. e.g. (t = [0:0.005:1] will give you five periods of the 5Hz wave and  seven of the 7Hz wave.)

Unfortunately there is no way to recover the phase shift data from the original signal with only the spectral data. However, the human ear cannot hear a phase difference in waves so perhaps this is suitable for your application.

If you'd like to learn more about he reconstruction of the wave you should look into how the Fourier Series is constructed.